# Hive - Unable to use PATINDEX in hive

Tags: hive

I am using string function PATINDEX in SQL to find the index of particular pattern match in string. I have a column in table named as volume which contains values such as 0.75L, 1.0L, 0.375L.

When I execute the below SQL query i.e.

```
select PATINDEX('%L%',VOLUME) from volume_details
o/p of query -> 5,4,6
```

But in hive query how to achieve the same since PATINDEX is not supported currently?

Comment: what should the outputs be?

Comment: output should be same as here..but is there such function in hiev to achieve the same.